# shell is repeating my command in the first line of the output?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

suddenly my shell is repeating my entered command in the first output line.
so the command `echo "hello world"` has following output:
`echo "hello world"`
`hello world`

i am using ZSH shell.

can you help me to turn back to standard behavior??


Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again (`exec zsh`)?

Comment: OMG it works!! This is embarrassing :D Thank you so much!